# how to create a dynamic Rshiny pannel

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

Im a newbie in Rshiny , how do i create  a  dynamic  pannel in the sidebar ? 
I do this but it doesnt work 
if there 's any other suggestions to do that ? 
    library(shiny)

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme="style.css",

  # Application title
  titlePanel("RNAseq app R "),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
              accept = c(
                'text/csv',
                'text/comma-separated-values',
                'text/tab-separated-values',
                'text/plain',
                '.csv',
                '.tsv'
              )
    ),
    tags$hr(),

    navlistPanel(

      tabPanel("Quality Control"),
      tabPanel("Trimming"),

      tabPanel("Alignement")


    )
  )

,

    mainPanel(
      )
    )))
```

server

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `conditionalPanel` to do that, in my example I also used `shinydashboard` as it is nicer

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="menu1",
                menuItem("Panel 1", tabName = "name1", icon = icon("th")),
                menuItem("Input A file", tabName =  "name2", icon = icon("th")),
                conditionalPanel(
                  condition = "input.menu1 == 'name2'",
                  fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                            accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'text/tab-separated-values','text/plain', '.csv','.tsv')),
                  selectInput("slider_test", "Some Dynamic Slider", choices = list("Years" = 1, "Months" = 2))
                ),
                menuItem("Panel 3", tabName = "name1", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody())
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

**Edit: Upload Pop-up using `shinyBS` package**

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="menu1",
                menuItem("Panel 1", tabName = "name1", icon = icon("th")),
                menuItem("Input A file", tabName =  "name2", icon = icon("th")),
                bsButton("upload", label = "Upload A file", block = TRUE, style="success"),
                bsModal("upload_popup", "Upload a File", "upload", size = "small",
                        fileInput('file2', 'Choose file to upload',accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'text/tab-separated-values','text/plain', '.csv','.tsv')),
                        bsButton("some_button", label = "Do Something Else", block = TRUE, style="success"))
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.menu1 == 'name2'",
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'text/tab-separated-values','text/plain', '.csv','.tsv')),
      selectInput("slider_test", "Some Dynamic Slider", choices = list("Years" = 1, "Months" = 2))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody())
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: isnt there anyway I can  ajust the position of the menu content , I want it to be right below each  item

Comment: Maybe I can create a pop-up which on click `input a file` button or something will pop-up a small window where you can upload your file?

Comment: No I added an explaination below check it out please